# In EMI calculations, how to calculate "Rate" if EMI, Principal and Time are given

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials, numerical-methods

In EMI (Equated Monthly Instalments) calculations, the inputs are- `Principal-P`, `Rate-r`, and `Time-n`. Can I calculate `r` if other 3 parameters are given i.e `P`, `n`, `EMI`?

I know the EMI formula is:

$$EMI = P*r*\frac {(1 + r)^n}{((1 + r)^n - 1)}$$

```
      where r  =  interest rate in month (annual rate/12),
            n =  time in months,  
            P  = principal amount
```

Can someone please tell how to derive the formula for calculating `r`, given other 3 parameters? I feel it requires Newton Raphson's method.

Comment: I am not sure if there is a simple formula other than numerical methods, If you want a numerical method, I shall give you one

Comment: @satishramanathan sure, please help me with one.

Answer (score 1):

This is a small program that you can put in any programming language to find the rate.  I am wondering why you would not want to use a financial calculator to get the rate.  I am a financial analyst and I calculate it almost 10 times a day with Financial Calculator.  This uses binary search algorithm to get the rate.

```
min_rate = 0; max_rate = 100; # Set Maximum and minimum rate

while (min_rate < max_rate - 0.0001)

{

  mid_rate = (min_rate + max_rate) / 2; # Divide by 2 to find midpoint

  J = mid_rate / 1200; # Convert to monthly decimal percentage

  # calculate payment based on this interest, term of N and loan_amt

  guessed_pmt = loan_amt *   ( J / (1 - (1 + J) ** -N ));

  if (guessed_pmt > actual_payment)

    { 

       max_rate = mid_rate; # current rate is new maximum 

    }

  else

    {

       min_rate = mid_rate; # current rate is new minimum

    }

}
```

Comment: I'll try this code. Can you suggest any financial calculator for the same?

Comment: Texas Instruments BA II Plus (including BA II Plus Professional) or Hewlett Packard 12C (including the HP 12C Platinum, 12C Platinum 25th anniversary edition, 12C 30th anniversary edition, and HP 12C Prestige)

Comment: You can also get it from the Rate function in EXCEL, By the bye, if you find my answer useful, please accept it